# How do i write this piece of code most efficiently using pandas and numpy

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have written a piece of code using pandas and numpy on my dataframe. It works but i am wondering how i can define a function to do the same thing and apply it to my dataframe.

```
import pandas

def f(row):
    if row['time_download'] == 0:
        val = 0
    else:
        val = (row['volume_download'] - row['volume_last_second'])/(row['time_download']/1000)
    return val

data['throughput'] = data.apply(f, axis=1)
```

this is extremely slow as my dataset is pretty large in the order of millions of rows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import where

no_download = data["time_download"] == 0

data["throughput"] = where(no_download, 0, \
    ((data["volume_download"].where(data["time_download"] != 0) - \
      data["volume_last_second"].where(data["time_download"] != 0))/\
      (data["time_download"].where(data["time_download"] != 0)/1000)))
```

i am receiving the expected results but i am a python beginner and am interested in understanding how to write this into a function since this is applicable to several columns grouped similarly,

Comment: [Fast, Flexible, Easy and Intuitive: How to Speed Up Your Pandas Projects](https://realpython.com/fast-flexible-pandas/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built in `pandas.DataFrame.div` function then convert the `Inf` values to 0.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# This will divide normally if time_download is not 0, otherwise will return Inf
df['throughput'] = (df.volume_download - df.volume_last_second).div(df.time_download)

# Locate all cells where throughput value is not finite (i.e. Inf) and set to 0
df.loc[~np.isfinite(df['throughput']), 'throughput'] = 0
```